# Example Infinite set and a bijection from the set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering if someone could give me an example of an infinite set and a bijection from the set to a proper subset of itself.

Comment: \begin{align}\mathbf N&\longrightarrow\mathbf N\\ n&\longmapsto 2n\end{align}

Comment: There's also $\mathbb N\to \{2,3,4,5,....\}$ via $n\mapsto n+1$.  And $\mathbb R$ to $(-\infty, 0]\cup [1, \infty)$ via $x\le 0\mapsto x$ while $x > 0\mapsto x+1$.  And there is $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ via $x\mapsto x+1$ if $x\in \mathbb N$ but $x \mapsto x$ otherwise.  And so on.

Comment: @Bernard  That is a bijection from $\mathbb N \to 2\mathbb N$ not from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.  As a function to $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ it isn't a bijection (it's not onto; nothing is mapped to the odd numbers).  Also $\mathbb N$ is not a proper subset of itself.

Comment: @fleablood: Why, yes!That's what the O.P. is asking for: the image is a proper subset of $\mathbf N$.

Comment: Yes, but you wrote "$\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$.  The function $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ via $f(n) = 2n$ is not a bijection.  The function $g: \mathbb N \to 2\mathbb N$ via $g(n) = 2n$ is, but $f$ is not.

Comment: You should consider that knowing that both $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ have the same countable cardinality means that there *must* be a bijection from $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb N$ (that's that *definition* of $\mathbb Q$ being countable) and $\mathbb N \subsetneq \mathbb Q$.  So that's an example.  And in proving that $\mathbb Q$ is countable you have probably *seen* this bijection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f: \mathbb N\rightarrow 2\mathbb N$$
$$n \mapsto 2n$$

It's a bijection from the set of all natural numbers $\{1, 2, 3, \cdots\}$ into its proper subset of all *even* natural numbers $\{2, 4, 6, \cdots\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer once stackexchange allows me to (8 minutes)

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

One example was given in the comments.  Here’s another:

$$n \mapsto n+1$$

is a bijection from {$0,1,2,...$} to {$1,2,...$} $\subsetneq $ {$0,1,2,...$}.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy and more general than you think.

If $f:A \to A$ is one to one then $f:A\to f(A)\subseteq A$ is onto and a bijection.  If $f:A \to A$ is *not* onto then $f:A \to f(A)\subsetneq A$ is a bijection to a proper subset.

So all we need is 1) An infinite set $A$.  2) An injective but not onto function from $A\to A$.

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ via $f(x) = e^x$ is one to one and will always have $e^x > 0$ and the image of $f$ is $(0,\infty)$.

So $f:\mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$ via $f(x) = e^x$ is an example.

But probably the very first one most of us have probably heard of is:

"You know, there are the same number of even numbers and numbers because for every number if you multiply it by $2$ you get an even number."

Most of us heard that in the first grade or so (and lost three weeks of sleep immediately afterward).

This is $f: \mathbb N \to \{$even integers$\}$ via $f(n) = 2n$ is such a bijection.

Less easy but maybe more fundamental and more to the point is:

we *know* $|\mathbb Q| = |\mathbb Z| = |\mathbb N|$ so *by definition* we know there are bijections from $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ and from $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb N$ and from $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$.

So we *can* say if $q\in \mathbb Q^+$ and $q = \frac ab > 0$ in lowest terms and we write down all the pairs of integers in the following order $(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(3,1),(2,2),(1,3), (4,1),(3,2),(2,3),(1,4),(5,1),(4,2),.....$ and we cross out all the pairs that are not relatively prime so we get $(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(3,1),(1,3),(4,1),(3,2),(2,3),(1,4),(5,1),(1,5),(6,1)....$ and count where $(a,b)$ appears in the list... then that is a bijection from $\mathbb Q^+ \to \mathbb N$.